# 3 way many to many relationship in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, many-to-many

I have a Person model, a Semester model, and a Room model.
I'm trying to do a 3 way many to many relationship.

I've achieved this with an associative entity (a 4th model), which has 3 foreign keys (one for Person, one for Semester, and one for Room).

What is the Django-ish way of doing this using the built in ManyToManyField? Or is it inappropriate to use that with a 3 way m2m? I was looking at funneling 2 ManyToManyFields using the through parameter, but I wanted to see if anyone else had figured this out.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to tell us your requirement, what relationship do you want to achieve. We cannot guess what `3 way many to many` are you trying to build up.

Comment: I think one extra model to keep the relationship (what you did) is the best way.

Comment: I am sure that it is not a many2many relationship because a person can use a room during more semesters. The room can be used by more people in the semester. A person can be related to more rooms in the semester. You need to clearly entitle the entity used for the relationship. You probably expect many filters, e.g. you want to restrict the relationship between Person and Room, restricted only to one Semester. The possible filters are so many that you should implement only the frequenty used of them as methods of model manager. Unfiltered m2m relationships don't seem to be helpful for you.

Comment: @ShangWang A room might have multiple people. A person will only have one room IN THAT SEMESTER.